# Why are some images not loading on capacitor ios app using vue and vite

Tags: vue.js, capacitor, vite

I am working on a capacitor app and it works fine both on browser and android phones but for one page when it's routed to it gets stuck on ios.
I have tried to check and saw it's because some files are not loading
[image]

This is my vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import vuetify from '@vuetify/vite-plugin'

import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
   vue(),
   // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
   vuetify({
    autoImport: true,
   }),
   alias(),
],
define: {
'process.env': {}
},
build: {
rollupOptions: {
  transformAssetsUrls: {
    img: ['src', 'data-src']
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      browser: true,
      preferBuiltins: false
    }),
    json()
  ]

  }
},
 resolve: {
    alias: {
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },

},
  server: {
    fs: {
    // Allow serving files from one level up to the project root
    strict: false
  }
},
css: {
   preprocessorOptions: {
    // global scss import
    scss: {
     charset: false,
     additionalData: `
     @import "@/styles/variables";
     @import "@/styles/mixins.scss";
     `
    }
  }
  }
 })
```

And this is how I am loading the images located inside src/assets folder:
[image]

I am using vue 3, vite 2.7 and capacitor 3

**Update:**
I'm not sure what was happening but the issue was occurring when I used vue `<component />` tag. I fixed it by rewriting that part

Answer (score 1):

You probably fixed this but since we fixed our, i'd like to share our solution.

We're building an app for iOS and Android using Quasar.js v2, vue3 and capacitor.

We had a similar problem when we built to production for iOS and Android.

In order To fix this we had to add `viteConf.base = '/'` in the build object in the quasar config file (which replaces vite.config.js), [doc for base shared options here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base)

```
    build: {
          extendViteConf (viteConf, { isServer, isClient }) {
            viteConf.base = '/'
          }...
```

Dependencies in package.json

```
    "@capacitor-community/firebase-analytics": "^1.0.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/clipboard": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/device": "^1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.9",
    "@capacitor/share": "^1.0.7",
    "@capgo/capacitor-updater": "^3.3.12",
    "@quasar/app-vite": "^1.0.5",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.14.3",
    "quasar": "2",
    "vue": "3",
```

Hope this can help